# Get Model Data in ajax request

Tags: magento2, controllers, ajax

I am making an ajax request in my module to grab some custom CRUD data to populate a select box on the fly.

I have a working ajax request and controller

**Javascript**

```
define(["jquery"], function($){
   return function(config, element) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'leadmodel/ajax/index',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        complete: function(response) {             
            console.log(response.responseJSON);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
      }); // ajax function end here

}
```

})

**Vendor/Module/Controller/Ajax/Index.php**

```
<?php 

namespace Vendorname\Modelname\Controller\Ajax; 

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action; 
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context; 

class Index extends Action { 

    protected $request; 

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ){ 
        parent::__construct($context, $data); 
    } 

    public function execute() { 

        $data = ['joe', 'bloggs'];

        $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $resultJson->setData($data); 
        return $resultJson; 
    } 
}
```

Which works fine, it console log's the array and everything is great. But as soon as I pass a factory into the controller to build an array with custom CRUD model data, it breaks the controller and I just get a 500 error.

```
<?php 

namespace Vendorname\Modelname\Controller\Ajax; 

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action; 
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context; 
use Vendorname\Modelname\Api\Data\LeadModelInterface;

class Index extends Action { 

    protected $request; 
    protected $_leadmodelCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Vendorname\Modelname\Model\ResourceModel\LeadModel\CollectionFactory $leadmodelCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ){ 
        $this->_leadmodelCollectionFactory = $leadmodelCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data); 
    } 

    public function execute() { 

        //Get the lead models
        $leadmodels = $this->_leadmodelCollectionFactory->create();

        //Start a new array
        $array = [];

        //Loop the lead models
        foreach($leadmodels->getLeadModels() as $leadmodel){
            $model = [];
            $model['name'] = $leadmodel->getLeadModelName();
            $model['id'] = $leadmodel->getId();
            array_push($array, $model);
        }

        $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $resultJson->setData($array); 
        return $resultJson; 
    } 
}
```

Am I doing this wrong? How am I supposed to get CRUD data from a model in the controller to pass back to my ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

change controller code with below code

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\Modelname\Controller\Ajax;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Vendorname\Modelname\Api\Data\LeadModelInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

class Index extends Action
{

    protected $request;
    protected $_leadmodelCollectionFactory;
    private $jsonFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Vendorname\Modelname\Model\ResourceModel\LeadModel\CollectionFactory $leadmodelCollectionFactory,
        JsonFactory $jsonFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_leadmodelCollectionFactory = $leadmodelCollectionFactory;
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        //Get the lead models
        $leadmodels = $this->_leadmodelCollectionFactory->create();

        //Start a new array
        $array = [];

        //Loop the lead models
        foreach ($leadmodels as $leadmodel) {
            $model = [];
            $model['name'] = $leadmodel->getLeadModelName();
            $model['id'] = $leadmodel->getId();
            array_push($array, $model);
        }

        $result = $this->jsonFactory->create();
        $result->setData($array);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still just getting `Internal Server Error - Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Vendorname\Modelname\Controller\Ajax\Index\Interceptor`

Comment: this is error is just because we chage the constructure argument, please remove that class from generator folder, and clear cache

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working? Am I definitely using the correct method to access model data in a controller?

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: I have changed my code and its working now, will upload my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what I was doing wrong, but I think it might have been the way I was trying to get the collection. I was trying to use a method called `getLeadModels()` which existed on the block.

I have changed my code to use the Lead Model Factory and the `getCollection` method and it seems to be working now.

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModelName\Controller\Ajax;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 

class Index extends Action {

    protected $request;
    protected $_leadmodelFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \VendorName\ModelName\Model\LeadModelFactory $leadmodelFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_leadmodelFactory = $leadmodelFactory;
    }

    public function execute(){

        //Get the lead models
        $leadmodels = $this->_leadmodelFactory->create();

        //Start a new empty array
        $array = [];

        foreach($leadmodels->getCollection() as $leadmodel){
            $model = [];
            $model['id'] = $leadmodel->getId();
            $model['name'] = $leadmodel->getLeadModelName();
            array_push($array, $model);
        }

        $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $resultJson->setData($array); 
        return $resultJson; 
    }
}
```